# Flutter Format Date

Tags: flutter, datetime

I facing a problem while converting the 'String' date into DateTime format. My Client's data source date format is '27-JAN-2022'. But keep I getting below error.

> Trying to read MMM from 27-JAN-2022 at position 3

I think it occurred based on the 'Month' value. Data Time can't identify 'JAN' but it's identified 'Jan'.

Please help me to convert the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parseLoose` method of `DateFormat`

```
DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy').parseLoose('27-JAN-2022')
```